# Running a  Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla as root user

Tags: wordpress, drupal, ubuntu

Is it advisable to run a wordpress/drupal or joomla production website as root on a ubuntu server ?

Any drawbacks for running it as non root ?

I somehow get the feeling that I should not allow my ubuntu's root access to the wordpress site.

Comment: It's more about not letting WordPress have access to the root account. The root account already has access to everything.

Comment: I think I mistook the wordpress root, to be my ubuntu root. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking about the `owners` and `groups` of the Wordpress and Joomla files and folders?

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions  That explains who needs to own Wordpress files, i.e. the FTP account owner:

> Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on
>   your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared
>   hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself
>   (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).